# ASP.NET MVC validation not working when overriding jquery validator method for date

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Here's my code for the model:

```
[LocalizedDisplay("Caption")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
string Caption { get; set; }
```

View code fragment:

```
....
$(function () {
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        Globalize.culture("he-IL");
        return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value) !== null;
    }
});
```

When I override the jQuery date validation method, the environment ignores the *"Required"* attribute of the *"Caption"* property in the model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
```

And if I just comment the abovestated javascript code - everything's working fine, except of validation for the date format *"dd/MM/yyyy"*.